# I want to use python to merge multiple TXTS into one TXT, but it shows me "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable". does anyone can help thanks

Tags: python-3.7

I want to use python to merge multiple TXTS into one TXT, but it shows me "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable". does anyone can help thanks:

```py
import os
sourceFileDir = 'C:\\Users\\QWE\Desktop\\10000_Tweet_Sample_Eng'
filenames = os.listdir(sourceFileDir)
file = open('C:\\Users\\QWE\\Desktop\\result.txt', 'r')
for filename in filenames:
    filepath = sourceFileDir + '\\' + filename
    for line in open(filepath):
        file.writelines(line)
        file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

Comment: please use code formatting (tripple backticks). A cleaner look makes it more likely you get your question answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the results file read only.

Try changing:

`file = open('C:\Users\QWE\Desktop\result.txt', 'r')`

To:

`file = open('C:\Users\QWE\Desktop\result.txt', 'w')`

For more details on how to use the open function, check here:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open

For your subsequent issues it maybe that the files you are opening require specific encoding, try changing:

`file = open('C:\\Users\\QWE\\Desktop\\result.txt', 'w')`

To:

`file = open('C:\\Users\\QWE\\Desktop\\result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

And:

`for line in open(filepath):`

To:

`for line in open(filepath, encoding='utf-8'):`

Comment: What encoding do the files you are opening have? Also please don't rewrite the question, now my answer is completely out of context for anyone else that has similar issues in the future.

Comment: Updated, you need to change both open lines as the files contain utf-8 characters, like Chinese characters. Also please remember to update the question with your original problem otherwise the answer will not make sense to others.